# FullCalendar event initialization from an array of objects problem

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am new with this fullCalendar and I have a little problem with event initialization.

I call a method from sendCalendarData servlet and i get the data separated by "*". After I parse it to object and push it to eventsArray I can't initialize the calendar with this data. I can call all of the details from the array, like title, start and end. I think it's well formatted and has everything.

Please help!

Thanks!

```
    var eventsArray = [];
    var objects = [];
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.post("/sendCalendarData", "", function(data, status) {
            var gotData = data.split("*");

            for (var i = 0; i < gotData.length-1; i++) {
                objects[i] = JSON.parse(gotData[i]);

                eventsArray.push({
                    title : objects[i].id,
                    start : objects[i].startDate,
                    end : objects[i].endDate
                });
            }

        })
        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: eventsArray                 
            })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was that the post function didn't finish when I called the calendar initialization, so the array didn't have data. I wrote a setTimeout and it's working.

Comment: A callback was even better. Thats my final solution for this